# How grails has implemented handler mappings?

Tags: grails, spring-mvc, controller, mapping, url-mapping

I have been trying to mock grails' convention over configuration paradigm in a spring mvc application and i am finding it difficult to automate handler mappings.

Basically i have a controller like this.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/contact"})
public class ContactController {

    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/index"})
    public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map){
        map.put("contact", new Contact());
        map.put("contactList", contactService.listContact());
        return "contact";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("contact")Contact contact, BindingResult result){

        contactService.addContact(contact);

        return "redirect:/contact/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{contactId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String removeContact(@PathVariable("contactId")Long contactId){
        contactService.removeContact(contactId);
        return "redirect:/contact/index";
    }
}
```

Now, i have tried "ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping", but it seems to have a limitation with three part url.

I basically want all the requests to be automatically mapped to the appropriate controller and actions, without using @RequestMapping

Any pointers will be great help

Answer (score 0):

That won't be easy. Grails framework has written bunch of ASTTransformers where they inject annotations and other properties in to the class which is controller. Take a look at the source code for grails-plugin-controllers and you cans see the code under compiler.web and see what they are doing. Also if you take a look at ControllersGrailsPlugin you will see that its watching the directory grails-app under the parent folder. It won't be that easy to do. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Making AST transformations [via ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) in your case, is probably the fastest way, maybe post-compilation step?

Hope it helps

---

It won't be that simple but what you want is likely to perform the following :

- Write an annotation processor(scan classpath from classloader) to collect Controllers annotations and matching class
- Hook into Spring mvc API to inject the Request Mapping based on your conventions.
- Then you would also need to collect the method parameters to auto-inject pathVariables, etc.

If Spring MVC is not expecting to play with the RequestMapping annotation as soon as the Controller annotation is found (or defaults to something), then you're good to go (Post Bean Definition processors or similar mechanisms)...

Not that simple, but definitely possible...